# Team status board

Tags: gratis, web-apps, project-management

I'm looking for a **free** (hosted) web application similar to [Rollcall](http://gorollcall.com) or [WorkingOn](https://www.workingon.co/), where members of a team (with more than 20 members) can post updates on what they are currently working on.

### Requirements

- Support for ~20 or more members
- Status updates can be tagged and searched by project
- Ability to quickly find out what someone is doing
- Ability to quickly find out who is working on a project
- Ability to assign more than one person to a project (about 5)
- Hosted

### Optional features

- Status updates can be commented on
- Integration with [Slack](http://slack.com)
- Integration with [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/apps/)
- Integration with [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com)
- Integration with [Asana](http://asana.com)

Comment: Have you looked up Scrum?

Comment: @user3097840 do you mean one of these: http://knowscrum.com/10-best-free-scrum-tools/ for example http://kunagi.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trello](https://trello.com/tour) may be worth a look.  It's basically like an online Kanban board so you can see easily what everyone's doing currently, what they've just done and what's in the backlog.  You can also create multiple Trello boards to organise your work or simply create colour-coded labels for different projects.

Furthermore, *"it’s free, now and forever"* according to their website.

Answer (score 2):

This [Kanban software](http://kanbantool.com/) provides:

- support for ~20 or more members
- ability to quickly find out what someone is doing (ask board)
- ability to quickly find out who is working on a project (team activity widget)
- ability to assign more than one person to a project (you can share boards, assign people to tasks and to-do lists)
- self-hosted version
- tasks can be commented on
- integration with Zapier

In addition it offers:

- time tracking and time reports,
- integration with Box, Dropbox, etc.

Comment: Nice match! Mind to [edit] your post and include what makes it "special", so the OP should decide for this and not one of "the other options"? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

We use [toggl.com](https://www.toggl.com/)

It does a good job to track activities, to have an instant status of who is working on which projects.

On top of that (and I believe this is their main idea) you can build timesheets in order to invoice your clients.
It is free, but I'm afraid it's only for 5 users.

Comment: Sorry - I'm expecting around 20 users, maybe more...